# Import excel files to sql server

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

I have files in xlsx format.  On average each one contains 2000 rows. I don't know how to import them to my database in SQL Server, should I create tables first or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio (**SSMS**) provides the Import Wizard task which you can use to copy data from one data source to another.  You can choose from a variety of source and destination data source types, select tables to copy or specify your own query to extract data, and save your work as an SSIS package.  In this section we will go through the Import Wizard and import data from an Excel spreadsheet into a table in a SQL Server database.

Have a look here :
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server's built-in import functionality.  It can create the tables for you right in the import wizard.  In SQL Server Management Studio, right-click on your database, choose "Tasks", then "Import Data".